# Remove elements from list by type

Tags: r

I have a list with two types of elements (1x1 data.frames and functions) that I got from scraping web pages. (I'm not even entirely sure how the function-type elements got in there -- there's probably 1 per every 100 data frames for some reason.) The issue is that because of the two different element types, I'm running into errors while trying to bind the rows, etc. I've tried a whole slew of ways to remove the function elements only (including !is.function, and is.data.frame) but for some reason that just returns all the elements in the list. I feel like maybe I'm missing something obvious — but if there's any ideas, that would be so helpful. Let me know if more info is needed.

Comment: You’re attempting to fix the symptoms rather than finding a cure. Don’t remove the function elements, find out where they are coming from and fix the causal bug! Apart from that, you’ll need to include the *exact code* you tried to get help with debugging.

Comment: if `x` is your list, try `x[sapply(x, is.data.frame)]`